# React with Antd form 3.0x props.form.getFieldsValue() always empty object

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

[image]

I want to get the data of props.form.getFieldsValue() whenever the Component unmounting, but the values is always empty Object?

Comment: Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You haven't given us enough code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Also, please see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)